# Swagger configuration for azure is different the for localhost

Tags: c#, azure, swagger

I have noticed that the only way to configure swagger to work for both localhost build and azure is to configure it in the following way:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
            {

                // For Debug in Kestrel
                x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
#if DEBUG
                x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // For localhost
#else
                x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; //  For azure
#endif
            }
            );
```

Does any one know why RoutePrifix has to be different for azure and localhost?

***Update***:

If I use configuration like this one:

```
// generated swagger json and swagger ui middleware
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
            {
                // For Debug in Kestrel
                x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
                x.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
            }
            );
```

Running it on the local computer is fine and it starts the browser at the start-up with the correct swagger UI page.

However if I publish my app (from within Visual Studio 2022) the process  starts at the end of the build the browser that display this page:
[image]

I don't understand why it does not insert `swagger` word in the URL - and because of that it comes with an error page.

Answer (score 1):

`x.RoutePrefix` property is to specify the base URL for the Swagger UI in ASP.NET Core applications.

**Local:**

- If you use `x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"` when the application is running on localhost, then Swagger UI will be available at `https://localhost:5001/swagger`
- Swagger UI uses the URL that you pass to `SwaggerEndpoint` to retrieve your API's metadata.
- By mentioning the default `RoutePrefix = "swagger"` for the `SwaggerUI middleware`, we are referring that the Swagger endpoint is available at `swagger/v1/swagger.json`.

[image]

When the application is deployed to Azure, the `x.RoutePrefix` is set to `string.empty`, because the application is hosted at the root URL, and the Swagger UI can be accessed through `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/swagger`

[image]

**I also tried few other cases:**

1. Using only `x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;`:

If we use an empty string when running the application locally, Swagger UI can be accessed by navigating to `https://localhost:<port>/index.html` ***locally*** and `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/swagger` in ***Azure***.

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
    x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; //  For azure
}
);
```

**Local:**

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

2. Using only `x.RoutePrefix = "swagger";`:

If we use ***swagger*** as ***RoutePrefix*** in the code, Swagger UI can be accessed by navigating to `https://localhost:<port>/swagger/index.html` ***locally*** and `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html` .

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
    x.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
}
);
```

**Local:**

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But which way to use it so it works for both cases? If I run my app locally I have to specify `x.RoutePrefix = "swagger";` if I run my app on azure I have to specify `x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` Is there a way to specify it such that it works for both cases?

Comment: It works if you specify both `x.RoutePrefix = "swagger";` and `x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` and it also works if you specify any one of them too, like the way I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Can you have a look at the Update section where I explain my problem in the different context. By saying it doesn't work I mean at the end of the publishing my app the process starts the page where it display an error "Can't find the page".

Comment: Try accessing your application via https://oloaschedulemebackend.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html, I could access, refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/eE2ndT7.png) .

Comment: Yep. That works but how do I make it the automatic running at the `oloaschedulemebackend.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html` at the end of the publishing process? Would you know?

Comment: I will check and update regarding that. As of now, to access automatically, you probably need to use both `x.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; and x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;`

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @janci, As per my research, this is the only approach to make it run automatically.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I wonder if your statement holds for the local environment when setting authorization for Swagger. I get it to work with **any** path (*swagger*, *swaggy*, *swaggerooni*, *beep* etc.) but **not** when I get it to `string.Empty`. The Swagger works as supposed to, yes, **but** it [won't authorize correctly in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78133569/swagger-wont-authorize-in-azure-when-served-from-root-although-working-fro?noredirect=1#comment137766938_78133569). Do you have any idea?